# Ruby on Rails: How to gather values for child tables from a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parent-child, erb

Referencing question #2013421, I have the following RoR models:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :piles
end

class Pile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
end
```

For the sake of argument, suppose `Game` has an attribute `name`, and `Pile` has an attribute `type`, both `string`. There are precisely 10 piles per game.

I would like a single HTML form to create a new Game, similar to the one generated by `ruby script\generate scaffold`; that is like:

```
<h1>New game</h1>

<% form_for(@game) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', games_path %>
```

How can I add fields to the form in order to read values for the `Pile.type` field for each of the 10 piles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

model:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :piles
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :piles
end
```

in your form:

```
 <% f.fields_for :piles do |pile_form| %>

   <%= pile_form.label :your_attribute %>
   <%= pile_form.text_field :your_attribute %>

 <% end %>
```

Consider that 'type' method-keyword-column is reserved by ActiveRecord to achieve polymorphic associations

see a [good guide about nested forms in rails](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes)

Comment: I see from the guide that accepts_nested_attributes_for is a Rails 2.3 feature. Sadly, my webserver is running on Debian using the apt-get packages, and so is only up to Rails 2.2.

However, playing about I've managed to make the f.fields_for incantation work to provide me an interpretable hash, which is all I need.

Comment: If apt-get packages are behind, install the gem, it's equally simple to using apt-get.

Comment: I don't own my webserver and my sysadmin is a sensible level of paranoid. While I'd be happy to install the gem, I respect his preference not to.