# Creating a set number of child objects from a parent's form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, parent-child

Thanks to [Ruby on Rails: How to gather values for child tables from a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020673) and "Agile Web Dev", I know how to have multiple models in a form using `fields_for`. But I'm tearing my hair out over this one.

Suppose I have a model `Person`. `Person` has a `name` attribute, and `has_many :foos`. The `Foo` model, in turn, has a `colour` attribute.

Furthermore, I know that each `Person` has *precisely three* `Foos`. What should my Models, the `new` and `create` actions in `PersonController`, and the `new` view look like in order to present three nicely-labelled text-entry boxes, one for each Foo and capable of reporting validation errors, to allow my "new person" form to create the whole set of four objects in one go?

Also, can I do this without `accepts_nested_attributes_for`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some playing about with varied locations for square braces and different for loops, I think I've solved this. Here's what my code looks like now (with routes set up as per scaffolding, so that posting from `/new` triggers `create`).

models/person.rb

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foos
  validates_presence_of :name
end
```

models/foo.rb

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  validates_presence_of :colour
  validates_uniqueness_of :colour, :scope => "person_id"
end
```

controllers/people_controller.rb

```
def new
  # Set up a Person with 3 defaulted Foos
  @person = Person.new
  (1..3).each { |i| @person.foos.build }
end

def create
  # Create (but don't save) a Person as specified
  @person = Person.new(params[:person])

  # Create (but don't save) a Foo for each set of Foo details
  @foos = []
  params[:foo].each do |foo_param|
    @foos << Foo.new(foo_param)
  end

  # Save everything in a transaction
  Person.transaction do
    @person.save!
    @foos.each do |foo|
      foo.person = @person
      foo.save!
    end
  end

  redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @person

rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
  @foos.each do |foo|
    foo.valid?
  end
  render :action => 'new'
end
```

views/people/new.html.erb

```
<% form_for :person do |f| %>
  <%= error_messages_for :object => [@person] + @person.foos %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>

  <table>
  <% @person.foos.each_with_index do |foo, index| @foo = foo%>
    <tr>
      <td><%= label :colour, "Foo colour #{index + 1}: " %></td>
      <td><%= text_field("foo[]", "colour" %></td>
    </tr>          
  <% end %>
  </table>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

This seems to do the trick.

Comment: Hmm. the uniqueness validation isn't quite working here. I'll try to figure that out.

Comment: No, I take it back. It was a bizarre interaction with my redirect and flash handling. I believe the code above works.